# Import option not available in quick fixes in eclipse (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```
public class sample_selenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

If I take the mouse over in Firefoxdriver I don't get the import driver option. the JAVA jar is added to the library. Don't know why this  is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see that you have the Selenium jars in your project. I think that you did not add the required jars to the project.
[Click here to go to selenium downloads.](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Go and download jars from Selenium Client section and add them to your project.

[Go to this site and follow the steps exactly if you are still not getting it.](http://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html)